# How do I convert ContextMenuEventArgs cursor location to window coordinates

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to display a context menu where the user clicks the mouse in a WPF application. I've handled the `OpenContextMenu` event and the handler has a pair of `doubles`, `e.CursorLeft` and `e.CursorTop` which are the coordinates of the mouse click relative to the control that was clicked (in this case a `DataGridCell`). If I display the context menu using those coordinates it appears relative to the application window offset by the cursor amounts.

How can I convert those `DataGridCell`-relative Cursor coordinates into window coordinate space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`UIElement.TranslatePoint(Point, Visual)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.translatepoint.aspx) method to convert coordinates from one control's coordinate space to another. The following code should do what you want *(not tested!)*:

```
Point target =
    myDataGridCell.TranslatePoint(new Point(e.CursorLeft, e.CursorTop), Application.Current.MainWindow);
```

However, if you only want to display a context menu, you could also simply assign the [`FrameworkElement.ContextMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.contextmenu.aspx) property for the control which should show the context menu. This way, the position will be positioned at the mouse cursor automatically. If you have a more complicated scenario, you might still use the method above.